# MongoDB Age Group Aggregation by Birthday Date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have MongoDB document like so:

```
{
    _id: {"$oid":"object_id"},
    email: "email@example.com"
    password: "password_hash"
    info: {
        birthday: "1993-03-12"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And I can't change it. I need to create Mongo query to group users by age (0-18 and 18+).
I don't know how to deal it. I've created only query that returns year from birthday date (which is string):

```
db.users.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                year: { $year: { date: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$info.birthday", format: "%Y-%m-%d" } } } }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

But I'm not sure what should I do futher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the age with this projection:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         birthday: {
            $dateFromString: {
               dateString: "$info.birthday",
               format: "%Y-%m-%d"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         age: {
            $subtract: [
               { $subtract: [{ $year: "$$NOW" }, { $year: "$birthday" }] },
               { $cond: [{ $lt: [{ $dayOfYear: "$birthday" }, { $dayOfYear: "$$NOW" }] }, 0, 1] }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8L7l71Buf4C)

Or if you prefer variables:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         age: {
            $let: {
               vars: {
                  birthday: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$info.birthday", format: "%Y-%m-%d" } }
               },
               in: {
                  $subtract: [
                     { $subtract: [{ $year: "$$NOW" }, { $year:  "$$birthday" }] },
                     { $cond: [{ $lt: [{ $dayOfYear: "$$birthday" }, { $dayOfYear: "$$NOW" }] }, 0, 1] }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Based on this age you can filter (i.e. `$match`) or `$group`

Comment: Thanks! excelent answer, just what I wanted.